# Google Sheets: Cell formula NOT working in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, spreadsheet, array-formulas, index-match

I've a regularly updating sheet of daily foreign exchange rates (descending order sorted).
I've written a cell formula, which works fine if I drag it to the end.
`=IFNA( VLOOKUP(A2,USD_TRY!$A$2:$B$3289,2,FALSE), INDEX(USD_TRY!$A$2:$C$3289, MATCH(A2,USD_TRY!$A$2:$A$3289,-1), 3 ) )`
Column `A2:A` is daily dates, merged from 2 different sheets of daily rates and different currencies (so it skips some dates) but it has more dates than the column `USD_TRY!A2:A`. This formula gets the `Price` rate from column `USD_TRY!B2:B` if the `VLOOKUP()` date matches but if it doesn't match then it gets the `Open` rate from column `USD_TRY!C2:C` a row before (a day after) the closest match. However, if I convert the same formula to `ARRAYFORMULA()` then the `VLOOKUP()` part works fine but the `INDEX(MATCH())` part gives a wrong result of `USD_TRY!C2` every time.

```
    IF(
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), NOT(ISBLANK('USD_TRY Historical Data'!A2:A)), NOT(ISBLANK('USD_TRY Historical Data'!B2:B)), NOT(ISBLANK('USD_TRY Historical Data'!C2:C)) ), 
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IFNA( 
        VLOOKUP(A2:A,'USD_TRY Historical Data'!A2:B,2,FALSE), 
        INDEX('USD_TRY Historical Data'!A2:C, MATCH(A2:A,'USD_TRY Historical Data'!A2:A,-1), 3 ) )
    )
    )
}
```

How do I correct the `ARRAYFORMULA()` and is there any simpler way to get the correct results as array?
Source data:
[image]
Correct output (with cell formula):
[image]
Wrong result (with array formula):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A4, E2:F6, 2, 0),  
 VLOOKUP(90000-A2:A4, {90000-E2:E6, G2:G6}, 2, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I used this formula:  
`ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA( VLOOKUP(A2:A,USD_TRY!A2:B,2,FALSE), VLOOKUP(90000-A2:A,{90000-USD_TRY!A2:A, C2:C},2,TRUE) ))`    

But it gives the `#REF!` error for the 2nd `VLOOKUP` with the explanation:    
`Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched array size. Expected 3290. Actual: 6643.`

Comment: @Shah-G error says that you need to change `C2:C` to `USD_TRY!C2:C`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. So basically we used `VLOOKUP` on descending sorted column. I wonder how can this work using `INDEX-MATCH`.